# Using Selenium and BeautifulSoup, how do I extract a javascript variable?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

url = 'https://gma-threads4thought.com/'

I've successfully scraped product title and price using BeautifulSoup however the quantity variable is behind javascript.

So my question is: How do I go about extracting the product.variants[0].inventory quantity.

My goal of this project is to have the data organized in XML and the only thing stopping me is this javascript variable

Any help is much appreciated!

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://gma-threads4thought.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
time.sleep(5)
#driver.quit()
results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-actions-4102174081087']")
print('Number of results', len(results))
data = []
product = driver.execute_script('$(function() { return product.variants[0].inventory_quantity;});')
```

Comment: Is the quantity you are looking for on the link page you provided? I see product title, price, discount amount, and size, but quantity only exists on the product details page. Are you referring to quantity on the product details page?

Comment: @Christine Quantity is the under the javascript <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants add-to-cart-form" id="product-actions-4102174081087" enctype="multipart/form-data">.  Inside the script tag there lies a product.variant[whatever_index].inventory_quantity. I need to extract this variable out of the script tag

Comment: I see what you mean now. I have an idea. I will post an answer and try to help.

Comment: @Christine I appreciate your help very much! With selenium I'm using the driver.execute_script method to try and extract the value but it's within a function so I'm having difficulty. I updated my post with what I have.

Comment: isn't quantity dependant on size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The html in the other answer is not loaded with javascript and can be accessed with a simple request with the Requests library (`pip install requests`). All I had to do was parse out the quantities (similarly to the other answer). Also, I noticed there was a different quantity for each size, so I included that in the final output.

## Code

```py
import requests, re, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://gma-threads4thought.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_products= {}
for i, product in enumerate(soup.find_all('div', class_='grid__item')):
    script = product.find('script').text
    all_quantities = []
    for section in script.split('\n'):
        section_rw = section.strip()
        if section_rw.startswith('var product = '):
            json_data = json.loads(re.search(r'({.*?});', section_rw).group(1))
            item_name = json_data['title']
            sizes = [size['title'] for size in json_data['variants']]
        if section_rw.startswith('product.variants'):
            quant = re.search('(\d+);', section.strip()).group(1)
            all_quantities.append(quant)

    product_quantities = {size: quant for size, quant in zip(sizes, all_quantities)}
    all_products[item_name] = product_quantities

print(all_products)
```

## Output

```
{'Malana Sports Bra - Raw Denim': {'XS': '40', 'S': '149', 'M': '195', 'L': '144', 'XL': '248', '1X': '197', '2X': '139', '3X': '89'}, 'Moto Skinny Legging - Raw Denim': {'XS': '59', 'S': '177', 'M': '190', 'L': '91', 'XL': '246', '1X': '246', '2X': '184', '3X': '73'}, 'Betty High Waist Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '29', 'S': '65', 'M': '67', 'L': '53', 'XL': '16', 'XXL': '5'}, 'Betty High Waist Legging - Heather Royal Burgundy': {'XS': '16', 'S': '40', 'M': '49', 'L': '32', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '6'}, 'Betty High Waist Legging - Heather Fig': {'XS': '15', 'S': '41', 'M': '49', 'L': '32', 'XL': '16', 'XXL': '7'}, 'Betty High Waist Legging - Heather Chambray': {'XS': '15', 'S': '37', 'M': '45', 'L': '28', 'XL': '10', 'XXL': '6'}, 'Betty Mid Rise Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '16', 'S': '39', 'M': '43', 'L': '28', 'XL': '14', 'XXL': '6'}, 'Betty Mid Rise Legging - Heather Royal Burgundy': {'XS': '17', 'S': '43', 'M': '49', 'L': '30', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '8'}, 'Betty Mid Rise Legging - Heather Fig': {'XS': '17', 'S': '39', 'M': '52', 'L': '33', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '9'}, 'Betty Mid Rise Legging - Heather Chambray': {'XS': '17', 'S': '40', 'M': '50', 'L': '31', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '7'}, 'Claire High Waist 7/8 Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '16', 'S': '34', 'M': '48', 'L': '24', 'XL': '9', 'XXL': '1'}, 'Claire High Waist 7/8 Legging - Heather Chambray': {'XS': '17', 'S': '42', 'M': '52', 'L': '32', 'XL': '15', 'XXL': '7'}, 'Claire High Waist 7/8 Legging - Heather Royal Burgundy': {'XS': '16', 'S': '43', 'M': '52', 'L': '33', 'XL': '16', 'XXL': '9'}, 'Claire High Waist 7/8 Legging - Heather Fig': {'XS': '17', 'S': '42', 'M': '49', 'L': '33', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '8'}, 'Claire Mid Rise 7/8 Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '14', 'S': '41', 'M': '48', 'L': '31', 'XL': '15', 'XXL': '7'}, 'Claire Mid Rise 7/8 Legging - Heather Royal Burgundy': {'XS': '17', 'S': '41', 'M': '50', 'L': '34', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '9'}, 'Claire Mid Rise 7/8 Legging - Heather Fig': {'XS': '17', 'S': '43', 'M': '50', 'L': '34', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '9'}, 'Claire Mid Rise 7/8 Legging - Heather Chambray': {'XS': '16', 'S': '42', 'M': '48', 'L': '33', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '8'}, 'High Rise Monica Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '104', 'S': '307', 'M': '334', 'L': '368', 'XL': '269', 'XXL': '102'}, 'Leigh Long Sleeve Scoop Neck - Raw Denim': {'XS': '12', 'S': '14', 'M': '4', 'L': '0', 'XL': '0'}, 'Leigh Long Sleeve Scoop Neck - Black': {'XS': '17', 'S': '22', 'M': '25', 'L': '0', 'XL': '3'}, 'Leigh Long Sleeve Scoop Neck - Ultra Maroon': {'XS': '14', 'S': '25', 'M': '16', 'L': '4', 'XL': '0'}, 'Leigh Long Sleeve Scoop Neck - White': {'XS': '15', 'S': '22', 'M': '11', 'L': '0', 'XL': '5'}, 'Liza Long Sleeve V-Neck - Raw Denim': {'XS': '15', 'S': '27', 'M': '26', 'L': '0', 'XL': '0'}, 'Liza Long Sleeve V-Neck - Black': {'XS': '15', 'S': '28', 'M': '20', 'L': '1', 'XL': '0'}, 'Liza Long Sleeve V-Neck - Ultra Maroon': {'XS': '20', 'S': '33', 'M': '26', 'L': '7', 'XL': '4'}, 'Liza Long Sleeve V-Neck - White': {'XS': '17', 'S': '38', 'M': '21', 'L': '10', 'XL': '2'}, 'Lunette Sports Bra - Black': {'XS': '11', 'S': '35', 'M': '36', 'L': '29', 'XL': '8', 'XXL': '2'}, 'Lunette Sports Bra - Heather Charcoal': {'XS': '12', 'S': '37', 'M': '35', 'L': '28', 'XL': '12', 'XXL': '0'}, 'Malana Sports Bra - Heather Chambray': {'XS': '13', 'S': '39', 'M': '42', 'L': '34', 'XL': '16', 'XXL': '3'}, 'Malana Sports Bra - Heather Charcoal': {'XS': '26', 'S': '63', 'M': '59', 'L': '39', 'XL': '20'}, 'Malana Sports Bra - Jet Black': {'XS': '11', 'S': '37', 'M': '38', 'L': '29', 'XL': '15', 'XXL': '4'}, 'Malana Sports Bra - Heather Royal Burgundy': {'XS': '12', 'S': '38', 'M': '41', 'L': '34', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '8'}, 'Malana Sports Bra - Heather Fig': {'XS': '12', 'S': '38', 'M': '43', 'L': '33', 'XL': '17', 'XXL': '9'}, 'Monica Legging - Jet Black': {'XS': '174', 'S': '513', 'M': '556', 'L': '624', 'XL': '449', 'XXL': '175'}, 'Sileni Thermal Top - Heather Grey': {'XS': '18', 'S': '51', 'M': '59', 'L': '38', 'XL': '13', 'XXL': '1'}, 'Sileni Thermal Top - Heather Charcoal': {'XS': '16', 'S': '51', 'M': '47', 'L': '34', 'XL': '16', 'XXL': '1'}, 'Thermal Jogger - Heather Grey': {'XS': '4', 'S': '27', 'M': '32', 'L': '23', 'XL': '8', 'XXL': '2'}, 'Thermal Jogger - Heather Charcoal': {'XS': '10', 'S': '35', 'M': '17', 'L': '13', 'XL': '7', 'XXL': '0'}}
```

Comment: Very cool, I can see how requests is a lot easier lol. So to add price I would just use price = json_data['price'] and append it to all products?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another idea, I can explain why your javascript doesn't work which the other 2 answers didn't.

First you don't have a return, so the return value will always be None. Second, the product variable is local to a scope that you don't have access to. So we have to run it again:

First get the script

```
script = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector("#product-actions-4102174081087 script").innerText')
```

Then remove the wrapper part which makes it out of scope

```
modified = re.sub(r'\$\(function\(\)\{|\}\);', '', script).strip()
```

Then run it, but include a return at the end:

```
variants = driver.execute_script(modified + ';return product.variants')
```